# Why am I getting a " instance has no attribute '__getitem__' " error?

Tags: python

Here's the code:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        root = [self.key, self.left, self.right]

    def getRootVal(root):
        return root[0]

    def setRootVal(newVal):
        root[0] = newVal

    def getLeftChild(root):
        return root[1]

    def getRightChild(root):
        return root[2]

    def insertLeft(self,newNode):
        if self.left == None:
                self.left = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(newNode)
            t.left = self.left
            self.left = t

    def insertRight(self,newNode):
        if self.right == None:
            self.right = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(newNode)
            t.right = self.right
            self.right = t

def buildParseTree(fpexp):
    fplist = fpexp.split()
    pStack = Stack()
    eTree = BinaryTree('')
    pStack.push(eTree)
    currentTree = eTree
    for i in fplist:
        if i == '(':
            currentTree.insertLeft('')
            pStack.push(currentTree)
            currentTree = currentTree.getLeftChild()
        elif i not in '+-*/)':
            currentTree.setRootVal(eval(i))
            parent = pStack.pop()
            currentTree = parent
        elif i in '+-*/':
            currentTree.setRootVal(i)
            currentTree.insertRight('')
            pStack.push(currentTree)
            currentTree = currentTree.getRightChild()
        elif i == ')':
            currentTree = pStack.pop()
        else:
            print "error:  I don't recognize " + i
    return eTree

def postorder(tree):
    if tree != None:
        postorder(tree.getLeftChild())
        postorder(tree.getRightChild())
        print tree.getRootVal()

def preorder(self):
    print self.key
    if self.left:
        self.left.preorder()
    if self.right:
        self.right.preorder()

def inorder(tree):
    if tree != None:
        inorder(tree.getLeftChild())
        print tree.getRootVal()
        inorder(tree.getRightChild())

class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

def main():
    parseData = raw_input( "Please enter the problem you wished parsed.(NOTE: problem must have parenthesis to seperate each binary grouping and must be spaced out.) " )
    tree = buildParseTree(parseData)
    print( "The post order is: ", + postorder(tree))
    print( "The post order is: ", + postorder(tree))
    print( "The post order is: ", + preorder(tree))
    print( "The post order is: ", + inorder(tree))

main()
```

And here is the error:

```
Please enter the problem you wished parsed.(NOTE: problem must have parenthesis to seperate each binary grouping and must be spaced out.) ( 1 + 2 )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Python Stuff\Assignment 11\parseTree.py", line 108, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Python Stuff\Assignment 11\parseTree.py", line 102, in main
    tree = buildParseTree(parseData)
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Python Stuff\Assignment 11\parseTree.py", line 46, in buildParseTree
    currentTree = currentTree.getLeftChild()
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Python Stuff\Assignment 11\parseTree.py", line 15, in getLeftChild
    return root[1]
AttributeError: BinaryTree instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 22):

Because you declared your methods wrong:

Lets have a look what happens if you call `tree.getRootVal()`. `.getRootVal()` is declared this way:

```
def getRootVal(root):
    return root[0]
```

As you probably know, the first parameter passed to a method is always the instance and it is provided implicitly. So you basically try to treat an instance of `BinaryTree` as a sequence(`root[0]`).

You have to specify it this way:

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.root = [self.key, self.left, self.right]   # self.root

    def getRootVal(self):
        return self.root[0]   # access self.root

    def setRootVal(self, newVal):
        self.root[0] = newVal

    # and also the other functions
```

The first parameter to an objects method does not have to be called `self`. But helps to do it this way in order to avoid errors like you did.

Interesting that you declared `insertLeft` and `insertRight` correctly ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that `root` should be `self.root`.

Your second problem is that here:

```
def getLeftChild(root):
    return root[1]
```

You are redefining root with a new meaning.

Answer (score 0):

As PreludeAndFugue says, you should fix the formatting. But from what I can gather, there is at least one error in your class methods in BinaryTree: most of them don't even take `self` as a parameter. Fix that and maybe you might be a bit better off.

Comment: I had just actually done that very same thing and it worked before looking back here.  Thank you two for your feedback.  I plan on using this site alot more for my snags.

Comment: But now im getting another problem.  In my postorder(tree) it finds the post order of a binary tree given to it, BUT im getting an error along the lines of:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Python Stuff\Assignment 11\parseTree.py", line 106, in main
    print( "The post order is: ", + postorder(tree))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'NoneType'

Any ideas?  Condidering the check at the beginning of it i dont see why its getting a 'NoneType' error.

Comment: I think you're trying to print a string and then the value of a variable, yes? I think I see the line where your error is occurring. I would suggest removing the "+". In python, you can just say: <code>print "The value of five is:", 5</code> and it will work as you would expect. If you throw a "+" in there, that's bad syntax. If you really want to use a "+", do <code>print "The value of five is:" + str(5)<code>. The "+" operator is used to concatenate strings and is therefore used badly in your example.

Comment: PS: in the future, please add a comment in your code annotating the line number. It makes it easier to trace your code back to the exact error line